# Adding properties in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to add C drive properties (free and used space) in order to get the total size.

`Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object -Property Free,Used`

This Shows the free and used space of drive C. I am able to convert them in GB using customized properties but not sure how to add those properties together. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised how there is so much online content on how to get the drive properties including Get-WmiObject but there is no information on how to get the total size whatsoever!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please have a look [How do I write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for suggestions on maximizing the audience your question reaches.  Specifically, I might recommend revising your title to include your actual question, and revising the question body to include the anticipated result.  On the latter, you're almost there but it's not quite clear whether you're trying to display two values, perform the math and display one value, store a variable, etc.  Good luck!

Comment: @FissureKing: May i know which part of the questions is not clear? He clearly mentioned that he want to add them together, since he is getting free and used space already.

Comment: @RanadipDutta specifically, does he/she expect this (or corrected) syntax to return the added value? or should this command be piped into a function that handles adding? where is the bottleneck?  is this a string manipulation issue, or a general powershell question?

Comment: If u have run the command , then you would have understood this part that he wants to achieve the total disk size,which by default is not there. So he want to sum the Used and Free size to get it done. Its pretty straight forward. Now I dont know how come function,string manipulation coming in picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $computerHDDs= Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk  -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"

 $logicalDisks = @()
foreach($item in $computerHDDs)
{
    $logicalDisk =[ordered]@{
    Name=$item.DeviceID -replace ':' ,'';
    DiskSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($item.Size/1GB) + " GB" ;
    }
 $logicalDisks +=$logicalDisk
 }

 $logicalDisks
```

Even in *psdrive* if you are able to get the free and used, then summation of both should give you the total size

***In your case, you can do like this***:

```
 $hdd= Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object -Property Free,Used
$total= (($hdd.free + $hdd.Used)/1GB).ToString() + " GB"
$total
```

**Note:** If you want to get the value only, then remove the tostring method and the GB part. Use the first portion only

And for all drives, you can use like this:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem | select Name, @{n= 'Used(GB)' ; e = {"{0:N2}" -f ($_.used/1GB)}}, @{n= 'Free (GB)' ; e = {"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Free/1GB)}}, @{n= 'Total(GB)' ; e = {"{0:N2}" -f (($_.used + $_.Free)/1GB)}} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: what does the -f do in the: `e = {"{0:N2}" -f ($_.used/1GB)}}`

Comment: @JeffS.: Using .NET to `Format` Numbers in Windows PowerShell

Comment: Go through the link for more understanding on this.[Formatting tips](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

PSDrive is not the best object to work with if you want full information on a hard drive partition, use the Volume cmdlets instead:

```
(Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).Size
```

or

```
Get-Volume -DriveLetter C | Select-Object Size
```

A PSDrive is an abstraction in PowerShell to treat various types of objects in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks! If I didn't name it add properties I would vote this as the correct answer since it is the easiest and shortest solution

Answer (score 0):

```
#solution 1 with new column into select
Get-Volume -DriveLetter C| 
select @{n= 'Used' ; e = {"{0:N2}" -f (($_.Size - $_.SizeRemaining)/1GB)}}, @{n= 'Free' ; e = {"{0:N2}" -f ($_.SizeRemaining/1GB)}}, @{n= 'Total' ; e = {"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}}

#solution 2 with foreach
Get-Volume -DriveLetter C| foreach {
[pscustomobject]@{
Used="{0:N2}" -f (($_.Size - $_.SizeRemaining)/1GB)
Free="{0:N2}" -f ($_.SizeRemaining/1GB)
Total="{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)
}

}
```